# Recursive Factorial ascending printing in JAVA

Tags: recursion

I 'm trying to do a recurisve factorial function. My first try was:

```
public static int printFactorial(int n){

        if(n<=1){
            System.out.println(n);
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(n);
            return printFactorial(n-1)*n;   
        }

    }
```

And it worked fine but my printing is:

```
3
2
1
```

It's cool but how can I get an ascending printing like this:

```
1 
2
3
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
public static int printFactorial(int n){
        int m=0;
        if(m==n){
            System.out.println(m);
            return m;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(m);
            return printFactorial(m+1)*m;   
        }

    }
```

But it didn't work. Why ?

Comment: Could you provide desired output for n = 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an iterative version of the factorial function, this is easy to do:

```
public static void printFactorial(int n) {

    int val = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        val *= i;
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```